# OnClick Handlers for Charts in GAS

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a GAS web deployed App which displays a few pie and column charts.
They are pulling data out of a Fusion Table and is mostly aggregate data based on some filters applied to the data.
The default charts are nice because when the you mouseOver the columns they display the some info related to the data.
What I would really like to do is to be able to click on a column and display in a new widget all the rows in the table that belong to that specific column(filter).

I've been searching for a while but could not find how to assign handlers to the charts. Is this not yet possible in GAS Charts?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to interact with the underlying Chart object to access the selection information it contains. There is an open issue on the topic, visit and star it to receive updates:

> [Issue 2351](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=2351): access the selected data in a Chart